# Libcurl supports multicast file transfer?

Tags: linux, libcurl, file-transfer

I want to know if libcurl supports the multicast file transfer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

curl is a command line tool for transferring data with URL syntax, supporting DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, Gopher, HTTP, HTTPS, IMAP, IMAPS, LDAP, LDAPS, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMTP, SMTPS, Telnet and TFTP. curl supports SSL certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP PUT, FTP uploading, HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, user+password authentication (Basic, Digest, NTLM, Negotiate, kerberos...), file transfer resume, proxy tunneling and

```
FEATURES

curl tool
 - config file support
 - multiple URLs in a single command line
 - range "globbing" support: [0-13], {one,two,three}
 - multiple file upload on a single command line
 - custom maximum transfer rate
 - redirectable stderr

libcurl supports
 - full URL syntax with no length limit
 - custom maximum download time
 - custom least download speed acceptable
 - custom output result after completion
 - guesses protocol from host name unless specified
 - uses .netrc
 - progress bar/time specs while downloading
 - "standard" proxy environment variables support
 - compiles on win32 (reported builds on 40+ operating systems)
 - selectable network interface for outgoing traffic
 - IPv6 support on unix and Windows
 - persistant connections
 - socks5 support
 - supports user name + password in proxy environment variables
 - operations through proxy "tunnel" (using CONNECT)
 - supports large files (>2GB and >4GB) both upload/download
 - replacable memory functions (malloc, free, realloc, etc)
 - asynchronous name resolving (*6)
 - both a push and a pull style interface

HTTP
 - HTTP/1.1 compliant (optionally uses 1.0)
 - GET
 - PUT
 - HEAD
 - POST
 - Pipelining
 - multipart formpost (RFC1867-style)
 - authentication: Basic, Digest, NTLM(*9), GSS-Negotiate/Negotiate(*3) and
   SPNEGO (*4) to server and proxy
 - resume (both GET and PUT)
 - follow redirects
 - maximum amount of redirects to follow
 - custom HTTP request
 - cookie get/send fully parsed
 - reads/writes the netscape cookie file format
 - custom headers (replace/remove internally generated headers)
 - custom user-agent string
 - custom referer string
 - range
 - proxy authentication
 - time conditions
 - via http-proxy
 - retrieve file modification date
 - Content-Encoding support for deflate and gzip
 - "Transfer-Encoding: chunked" support for "uploads"

HTTPS (*1)
 - (all the HTTP features)
 - using client certificates
 - verify server certificate
 - via http-proxy
 - select desired encryption
 - force usage of a specific SSL version (SSLv2(*7), SSLv3 or TLSv1)

FTP
 - download
 - authentication
 - kerberos4 (*5), kerberos5 (*3)
 - active/passive using PORT, EPRT, PASV or EPSV
 - single file size information (compare to HTTP HEAD)
 - 'type=' URL support
 - dir listing
 - dir listing names-only
 - upload
 - upload append
 - upload via http-proxy as HTTP PUT
 - download resume
 - upload resume
 - custom ftp commands (before and/or after the transfer)
 - simple "range" support
 - via http-proxy
 - all operations can be tunneled through a http-proxy
 - customizable to retrieve file modification date
 - no dir depth limit

FTPS (*1)
 - implicit ftps:// support that use SSL on both connections
 - explicit "AUTH TSL" and "AUTH SSL" usage to "upgrade" plain ftp://
   connection to use SSL for both or one of the connections

SCP (*8)
 - both password and public key auth

SFTP (*8)
 - both password and public key auth
 - with custom commands sent before/after the transfer

TFTP
 - download / upload

TELNET
 - connection negotiation
 - custom telnet options
 - stdin/stdout I/O

LDAP (*2)
 - full LDAP URL support

DICT
 - extended DICT URL support

FILE
 - URL support
 - "uploads"
 - resume

FOOTNOTES
=========

  *1 = requires OpenSSL, GnuTLS, NSS, yassl, axTLS or PolarSSL
  *2 = requires OpenLDAP
  *3 = requires a GSSAPI-compliant library, such as Heimdal or similar.
  *4 = requires FBopenssl
  *5 = requires a krb4 library, such as the MIT one or similar.
  *6 = requires c-ares
  *7 = requires OpenSSL or NSS, as GnuTLS only supports SSLv3 and TLSv1
  *8 = requires libssh2
  *9 = requires OpenSSL, GnuTLS, NSS or yassl
```